# command line parameters for firefox

Tags: firefox

I am running program which open "chromium-browser" with following command-line parameters in Linux.

```
--incognito = Causes the browser to launch directly in incognito mode. ↪

--no-first-run = Skip First Run tasks, whether or not it's actually the First Run. Overridden by kForceFirstRun. 
                    This does not drop the First Run sentinel and thus doesn't prevent first run from occuring the 
                    next time chrome is launched without this flag. 

--disable-save-password-bubble

--password-store = Specifies which password store to use (detect, default, gnome, kwallet). 
--password-store=basic

--no-default-browser-check = Disables the default browser check. Useful for UI/browser tests where we want to avoid having 
                                the default browser info-bar displayed.

--window-size = Specify the initial window size: --window-size=w,h 
--window-size=1024,1024

--app = Specifies that the associated value should be launched in "application" mode.
```

Now I want to do the **same thing with** "firefox" browser. I need help to find firefox command-line parameter for firefox which is similar to chromium-browser.

**I searched firefox website but not able to find alternatives for same.**

Comment: Just be aware, Chromium is not Firefox.  Two different apps designed by two different organizations.  There's no guarantee that the same functionality will be available in both.  In fact, I think many of the options you mention for Chromium simply do not and probably never will exist for Firefox.  You can always ask, but likely be denied.  There are issues of higher priority that routinely go 10+ years without being fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to look them up here [Mozilla - Command Line Options](https://www-archive.mozilla.org/docs/command-line-args) remember: Mozilla is the umbrella organisation of firefox, thunderbird, ... so this looks like the normative documentation place - the reality check then will be the installed binary, but then you can file issues in the tracker (if an option similar to these needed by you is documented but does not work).

Update 2021-08-30: Note that the options page is in archive status and there may be non-listed options available or listed options missing with newer versions. Until the Mozilla / Firefox project comes up with a maintained manual page on these options a good way to ensure what options are supported is to call firefox on the command line with the `--help` parameter.

Comment: that link is dead now (Page not found)

Comment: @DavidBalažic thanks. It seems Mozilla does not advertise these as before - so I placed the archive link the vendor/organization chose yielding the content as 5 years ago (give or take)

Comment: FYI: that list is incomplete, for example it is missing the `--allow-downgrade` option is not listed.

Comment: @DavidBalažic thanks, see my update to the answer

Comment: Note that `firefox --help` doesn't work on Windows, unless you've got a debug build of Firefox. You need to run `firefox --help | more` instead in the command line (see [26761](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26761)).

Comment: @PetrBodnár wow awesome tip I had no idea why I couldnt see the help output on windows.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to check [this one](http://www.devdoc.net/web/developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options.html)
this works as of 21/10/21

Answer (score 1):

You would also want to look at the '-kiosk' argument
(similar to the chromium '--app' arg) which isn't really documented in the pages referenced in other comments here.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-enterprise-kiosk-mode